# Bench marking ARM NEON OpenMAx Numbers

Tags: arm, benchmarking, neon, fpu, openmax

I am currently working on bench marking the performance of Cortex-A8 processor by using various compilers(tried DS-5 and IAR) and various libraries (Openmax,NE10). 
I am specifically working on to see what NEON unit can achieve when compared 
1.Only ARM
2.ARM +VFPv3

Openmax is available from in two versions 1. Custumized for NEON
2. Sample code for Arm processors
I made the following table using OpenMax. As expected NEON code performance is unparalleled.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B318pI7x2QVceWRDTE5FQk8zcVk/edit

NE10 is the only other Signal processing library currently available for Cortex-A.I am still working on NE10 library.

**Is there any way I can compare these numbers with other processors? or there any programs standard programs for comparing processors?**

The following is the link to Openmax api 
http://www.khronos.org/files/openmax_dl_spec_1_0_2.pdf