# How to Build & Decode using OpenMAX Development Layer (DL) By ARM

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, neon, openmax

I have tried study long time some easy way to build and utilize ARM Optimized OpenMax DL Library without success which is available here https://silver.arm.com/browse/OX002 but need login to download.

No easy to use api could be found to decode or easy compile instruction of high level library(FFMpeg) which could utilize OpenMAX DL.

I got some hope to get ans on stackoverflow because of some similer discussion here [Bench marking ARM NEON OpenMAx Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722534/bench-marking-arm-neon-openmax-numbers)

What I want to achieve is to build OpenMax DL with Gnu Compiler and could decode some samples on Cortex A8 to see and use performance difference.

Any suggestion or pointer on how to do that will be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

PV

Answer (score 2):

I am the one who posted the question. The libraries can be compiled or can be simply be used by including the source code  of the file you want to use. There are three versions of the Openmax library,
One version is in c https://silver.arm.com/browse/OX000 (can be compiled with any compiler)   .

The second version is NEON specific code https://silver.arm.com/browse/OX002 . This can be directly compiled using ARM's compiler like armcc, if you want to compile using some other compiler like GCC you need to make changes in the assembly macros,code remains the same . The changes are simple changes in macros and compiler directives...

The third version is for arm11.

Please specify any specific problem so that I can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for information.

We can build DL Library with that but my point is how to use that lib I mean there is no simple api call for decode. Should I use some library on Top of (DL) to simplify uses of that codec ? is there any sample code available which I can build on top of that DL and decode AAC ?

Comment: Dude i am not in to codecs and stuff . I just used filters and FFt after reading the doc http://www.khronos.org/files/openmax_dl_spec_1_0_2.pdf